# Run-time error '13': Type mismatch when I input a Range of Cells

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I have a VBA code that searches a directory for folders based on a partial name.
The partial names are in column F, the code returns the folder name and folder path.

For example, the folder path is "C:\Users\Dunelle\Desktop\10001-Rev1

The last part of the path (Rev1) changes but the 10001 remains unchanged. I need to perform a search using the wildcard `10001*`.

The partial names are in column F and I want to return the search with folder name in column A on the same row and return the folder path in column B on the same row when I enter a value in column F.

The code I have written works when a single cell is referenced.
However, I get an error 13 type mismatch error when I change the range to ("F:F").

This is the code I have:

```vb
Sub SearchName()
    Dim ENumber As Range
    Dim ECell As Range
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim rownumber As Integer
    Dim varDirectory As Variant
    Dim strDirectory As String

    Set ENumber = Range ("F:F")

    rownumber = ENumber.Row

    strdirectory = "C:\Users\Dunelle\Desktop\" & ENumber & "*"
    varDirectory = Dir (strDirectory, vbDirectory)

    For Each ECell In ENumber.Cells
        If ENumber <> "" Then
            Cells(rownumber, 1) = varDirectory
            Cells(rownumber, 2) = strDirectory + varDirectory
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next ECell
End Sub
```

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: What is a `rownumber` of an entire column?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the range to a defined one, like this:

`Set ENumber = Range("F1:F10")`

Or if it's a variable length range:

`Set ENumber = Range("F1:F" & Range("F1").End(xlDown).Row)`

Comment: thank you for the swift response. I have tried your suggestions, still getting the error 13 type mismatch. If I use Set ENumber = Range("F1") or any other cell in column F, it works. As soon as I enter a range, the type mismatch error comes up. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can't name an entire range into one string, `strDirectory`. You must only select a single cell from that range at a time. You just need to move 3 lines into the `For` loop.

Try this:

```
Sub SearchName()
    Dim ENumber As Range
    Dim ECell As Range
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim rownumber As Integer
    Dim varDirectory As Variant
    Dim strDirectory As String

    Set ENumber = Range ("F:F")

'Move the next 3 lines into the loop and change `Enumber` to `Ecell`
    'rownumber = ENumber.Row
    'strdirectory = "C:\Users\Dunelle\Desktop\" & ENumber & "*"
    'varDirectory = Dir (strDirectory, vbDirectory)

    For Each ECell In ENumber.Cells
        strDirectory = "C:\Users\Dunelle\Desktop\" & ECell & "*"
        varDirectory = Dir(strDirectory, vbDirectory)
        rownumber = ECell.Row
        If ENumber <> "" Then
            Cells(rownumber, 1) = varDirectory
            Cells(rownumber, 2) = strDirectory + varDirectory
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next ECell
End Sub
```

Side note: You have `Exit Function` in the `For` loop. It should say `Exit Sub`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your suggested answer above, still getting the type mismatch error.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the code you suggested, I was convinced it'd work until the error message came up again. Might have to devise a work around if I can't get it to work. Thanks so much

Comment: I tested it and it worked. What line are you getting the error on?

Comment: I'm sorry, I see I wasn't so clear. On those 3 lines that are moved, change `Enumber` to `Ecell`. 
I will update my answer.

Comment: Moshe W, thank you so much. Worked perfectly, you genius! Take care and see you around :)